# Why are planetary orbits stable given accumulation of forces due to solar wind?

Tags: photons, momentum, sun, solar-system, solar-wind

The solar system is more than 4 billion years old. Ever present solar winds which emanates from the sun consists of photons, hydrogen and helium. The momentum transfer from photons upon contact with mass is not insignificant. So would hydrogen and helium particles transferring their momentum upon contact.

[image]

The push from the solar winds is perpetually ongoing, and always directed radially away from the sun. Over 4+ billion years accumulation, *why is there no radial velocity of the planets spiralling away from the sun, due to this ever present solar wind*?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we do not know is Solar system is indeed stable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System). Second, the presence of a steady supply of momentum just means a correction to the centripetal force experienced by a planet (by Newton's second law $\vec{F}=\frac{d \vec{p}}{d t}$. This will just change the radius of the orbit a bit, and will not affect the stability.
You might say that the solar wind can vary in time but then there stronger time dependent forces acting on planets (e.g. gravity from other planets), and the question whether these can destabilize the solar system is still open (see the link above).

Comment: Thank you. Let's suppose that the earth is indeed pushed constantly by the sun's solar wind particles. Then with each revolution of the earth (every 365 days), the traced orbit will be slightly larger than the previous orbit like a spiral. Wouldn't this constant outward bulging of the earth's orbit with each revolution be easily detectable, especially in the last 100+ years since measurements have become so precise?

Comment: @James. This is what the answer tries to explain to you: If the Earth is constantly pushed by the same solar wind, this effect will NOT accumulate. It just changes the effective force the Sun exerts on the Earth. This would NOT mean that the orbit is a spiral.

Comment: @Koschi thank you, i believe i understand it now. The effective gravitation pull of the sun will be subtracted ever so slightly by the solar wind in the opposing direction. Because net gravity is slightly smaller, the earth's orbit will be larger than it would otherwise be, but the effect won't accumulate over time, it would just meen a slightly larger orbit for the earth than if solar winds were absent?